# Invalid conversion from int to int** C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Not sure why I'm getting this error. I have the following:

```
int* arr = new int[25];

int* foo(){
   int* i;
   cout << "Enter an integer:";
   cin >> *i;
   return i;
}

void test(int** myInt){
   *myInt = foo();
}

This call here is where I get the error:

test(arr[0]);   //here i get invalid conversion from int to int**
```

Comment: It's not the source of the compile error, but you have a logic error in 'foo()' - you declare a pointer but never initialize it. When you execute that function it will (in all likelihood) crash.

Comment: Hopefully it will crash.  It might not, which would be quite a bit worse.  Uninitialized pointers == baaaaad.

Comment: I removed the tags about function pointers and member pointers; your question is just about data pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you've written it, `test` takes a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, but `arr[0]` is just an `int`.

However, in `foo` you are prompting for an `int`, but reading into a location that is the value of an uninitialized pointer. I'd have thought you want `foo` to read and return and `int`.

E.g.

```
int foo() {
   int i;
   cout << "Enter an integer:";
   cin >> i;
   return i;
}
```

In this case it would make sense for test to take a pointer to an int (i.e. `void test(int* myInt)`).

Then you could pass it a pointer to one of the `int` that you dynamically allocate.

```
test(&arr[0]);
```